# Finding position of endpoint on an ellipse's perimeter given axes

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, conic-sections

Given the semiaxes and $d$ (where $d$ starts at the semimajor axis and ends at point $A$), is there a formula to calculate the position of the endpoint on the ellipse perimeter?

In my case, the semimajor axis $(a) = 5$, the semiminor axis $(b) = 4$, and $d = 4.12$.

[image]

Comment: *Welcome to the site !*. Why don't you write the equations first ?

Comment: are you looking for the polar equation to compute $\int rd\theta =d$?

Comment: Thank you Claude!  I wasn't sure of what the formula was, though.  Anindya, I think so?  It's been many years since I last took a math class.  Basically, I am looking to find the coordinates for A, will that formula give that to me?  And how do I use it?

Comment: The points of an ellipse are connected to the arc length of this ellipse through "complete elliptic integrals of the first kind". See p. 165 of these exceptional notes by Jack d'Aurizio https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your responses.

What I ended up doing was a more basic approach.  I created a function to solve for y using the ellipse formula (((x^2)/a^2))+((y^2)/(b^2))=1, rewritten as:

y2 = Perihelion * Sqr(1 - ((x2 ^ 2) / (Aphelion ^ 2))), and with the y value I added the distance between the points to the 'sumarclength' until it equaled the actual arc length, with considerations for arc lengths over 180deg.

for the below =>

```
Aphelion = vAphelion.Value
Perihelion = vPerihelion.Value
EllipsePerimeter = 2 * Application.WorksheetFunction.Pi() * Sqr(((Aphelion ^ 2) + (Perihelion ^ 2)) / 2)
TotalTravel = ((vTimePIElapsed * vOrbitalSpeed.Value) + vOrbitalRotationInitialOffset.Value) / 1000000
FullRotations = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(TotalTravel / EllipsePerimeter, 0)
ExpArcLength = TotalTravel - (EllipsePerimeter * FullRotations)
OrbitDriection = f

If ExpArcLength > 0.5 * EllipsePerimeter Then
  ExpArcLength = ExpArcLength - (EllipsePerimeter * 0.5)
  SumArcLength = 0
  x1 = -Aphelion
  y1 = 0
  For xc = -Aphelion To Aphelion Step 0.0001
    x2 = xc
    y2 = Perihelion * Sqr(1 - ((x2 ^ 2) / (Aphelion ^ 2)))
    AddArcLength = Sqr(((x2 - x1) ^ 2) + ((y2 - y1) ^ 2))
    SumArcLength = SumArcLength + AddArcLength
    x1 = x2
    y1 = y2
    If SumArcLength > ExpArcLength Then Exit For
  Next xc
  modY = 1
Else
  SumArcLength = 0
  x1 = Aphelion
  y1 = 0
  For xc = Aphelion To -Aphelion Step -0.0001
    x2 = xc
    y2 = Perihelion * Sqr(1 - ((x2 ^ 2) / (Aphelion ^ 2)))
    AddArcLength = Sqr(((x2 - x1) ^ 2) + ((y2 - y1) ^ 2))
    SumArcLength = SumArcLength + AddArcLength
    x1 = x2
    y1 = y2
    If SumArcLength > ExpArcLength Then Exit For
  Next xc
  modY = -1
End If
OrbitalDistance = Sqr((x2 ^ 2) + (y2 ^ 2))
OffsetX = x2
OffsetY = y2 * modY
```

Its not the "math" way I was trying to do it but it is pretty accurate